# Создание и выполнение одноразовых задач по времени с точностью до секунды

Tags: php, linux, windows, cron

Какой существует лучший способ для создания и выполнения одноразовой запланированной задачи на windows/linux?

Простой пример - соц. сети и публикация записи. Каждый пользователь может создать запись и указать любое время с точностью до минуты для публикации.

Решение в лоб - пишем информацию в базу о публикации, каждую минуту выполняем cron/задачу в планировщике и проверяем есть ли записи, которые необходимо опубликовать. Но мне кажется это не самое лучшее решение.

И если, допустим, речь идёт про публикацию с точностью до секунды. Как это реализовать?

Делать 60 * 60 * 24 cron/задач в планировщике каждую секунду - это не убийство сервера? Речь не идёт про highload и big data, хочется понять как "правильно" решить эту задачу не в лоб, допустим, если нужно планировать несколько тысяч таких задач ежедневно, но в произвольное время с точностью до секунды. Время заранее неизвестно. Такие задачи создают пользователи динамически.

Comment: С помощью поля `ACTIVE_FROM` которое хранит время начала активности. Запрос на показ выбирает соответственно `WHERE ACTIVE_FROM < now()`

Comment: Наверное вам нужена команда [at](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-schedule-tasks-using-at-command-on-linux)